# Is there a way to get httpd to delete its /tmp .upload files? (Linux, 2.4 httpd)

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server

We have an httpd webserver which is used to upload files (among other things). The files are uploaded to the systemd /tmp directory for httpd, but are often not deleted. Worse yet, lsof often shows that the file descriptor is still held by httpd, sometimes long after the upload has completed.  Is there any way to configure httpd to delete these files once the upload completes?  This is a small system, without much disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job to delete the contents of your *systemd /tmp* directory every hour or so.

Instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) (related to ubuntu, but should be essentially the same)

Comment: A cron job would suffice if httpd always released the file descriptor.  Since it doesn't, an "rm" of the file will not release the space back to the OS.  The other problem with a cron job is that you can't be sure if an upload is in progress - removing the file during an upload would be more problematic.